# jquery input search image list highlight by alt

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a list of images styled using a CSS class that I can use to find the elements in code (if it is necessary).

I would like to have an input that filters my list, by highlighting (ie. Removing my styling class or adding another style) any images that have an alt text which matches the input value.

I hope this is understandable - if not, I can clarify further. Thank you!

Comment: share your html sample and what you have tried

Comment: sample code will be helpful.

Comment: _the image that have the alt tag **same the input**._ what does this means?

Answer (score 0):

try this

`$("img[alt="+yourText+"]").addClass("somePredefinedClass")`

Comment: _the image that have the alt tag same the input._ what do you get it from here?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be along the lines of what you're looking for:

Where your input has an id of "myInput",

and your saturated class name = "mySaturateClass",

and your image class name = "myImage":

```
$("#myInput").change(function () {
    var searchTerm = $("#myInput").val();
    $(".myImage").addClass("mySaturateClass");
    $(".myImage[alt=" + searchTerm + "]").removeClass("mySaturateClass");
});
```

Depending on how you're using the saturation, you might want to swap the `addClass` and `removeClass` methods. Hope this helps!